# setuptools: ImportError on load_entry_point

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py, entry-point

I'm trying to create an entry point when installing my package.
Here is my package:

```
.
├── foo
│   ├── example.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

My setup.py is:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


console_scripts = \
    ['foo.py = foo.example:main']

setup(name='foo',
      version='1.1.1',
      author='me',
      author_email='me',
      url='',
      entry_points={'console_scripts': console_scripts},
      include_package_data=True,
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=False)
```

And this is example.py:

```
def main():
    print "hello world"
```

I'm installing like so:

```
python setup.py sdist
pip install dist/foo-1.1.1.tar.gz
```

It works fine. But when I try to use the entry point /usr/bin/foo.py I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/foo.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('foo==1.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'foo.py')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 570, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2751, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2405, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2411, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named example
```

importing the foo module in python shell works fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

You named your entry point script `foo.py`. When you run it any import from `foo` import from the script. That is, you shadowed your package `foo`. The script doesn't have submodule `example` hence the error.

Do not name the script `foo.py`, name it just `foo`:

```
console_scripts = \
    ['foo = foo.example:main']
```

Or name it `bar.py` if you need `.py` extension. That way it wouldn't shadow package `foo`.